# Passing arguments to objective functions in Python optimize.root

Tags: python, optimization, lambda, scipy

I'm using `optimize.root` to find a numerical solution to a system of equations. I need to express each condition as a separate function, and I also need to pass an argument to some of the conditions. It seems, however, that `optimize.root` can only pass the arguments correctly if the calculation is done within the objective function itself, and not in a separate function called by the objective function.

The following code replicates the problem:

```
# Conditions to be solved
def fSSBj(inp):
    return (0.5*inp[1])/(1+inp[1])-0.9*inp[0]
def fSSBJ(inp):
    return inp[0]-inp[2]*inp[1]

# Objective function with conditions inserted directly
def objFunc1(inp,pM):
    out = empty(2)
    out[0] = (0.5*inp[1])/(1+inp[1])-0.9*inp[0]
    out[1] = inp[0]-pM*inp[1]
    return out

# Objective function that calls the functions with the conditions
def objFunc2(inp,pM):
    out = empty(2)
    out[0] = fSSBj(inp+[pM])
    out[1] = fSSBJ(inp+[pM])
    return out
```

Note that both objective functions use the same input; they also give the same output:

```
print objFunc1([1.0,1.0],0.2)
print objFunc2([1.0,1.0],0.2)
```

Both these commands return

```
[-0.65  0.8 ]
```

The problem, however, is that the following two commands give very different results:

```
Out1 = optimize.root(objFunc1, [1.0,1.0], args = (0.2), method='hybr')
Out2 = optimize.root(objFunc2, [1.0,1.0], args = (0.2), method='hybr')
```

The first works just fine; the second gives an error message (`Index is out of bounds`). Could there be a problem with how `optimize.root` transfers the arguments to a function?

This is a problem for me, because (1) I have different sets of conditions to solve; and (2) I need to take first derivatives to make the Jacobian function. For these two reasons I am using SymPy's `lambdify` function to make the functions and their derivatives, and include them in the objective function.

Comment: They are not identical. should "out[1] = inp[0]-pM*inp[1]" be "out[1] = inp[0]-inp[2]*inp[1]"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `numpy` casts your input list to an `ndarray`.

Unfortunately,

```
>> [1,1] + [0.2]
[1, 1, 0.2]

>> np.array([1,1]) + [0.2]
array([ 1.2,  1.2])
```

Therefore, you get an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

That was the hint I needed! When I use `numpy.concatenate` it works. Below the working code:

```
# Conditions to be solved
def fSSBj(inp):
    return (0.5*inp[1])/(1+inp[1])-0.9*inp[0]
def fSSBJ(inp):
    return inp[0]-inp[2]*inp[1]

# Objective function that calls the functions with the conditions
# Use numpy.concatenate to concatenate the numpy arrays
def objFunc(inp,pM):
    out = empty(2)
    allInp = concatenate((inp,pM))
    out[0] = fSSBj(allInp)
    out[1] = fSSBJ(allInp)
    return out

# Be sure to give the argument as a list:
Out = optimize.root(objFunc, [1.0,1.0], args = ([0.2]), method='hybr')
```